# returning all DOM elements using a reusable function

Tags: javascript, html

I want my 4 anchor tags in my HTML file to change their css properties simultaneously. So I created a reusable function called `query()` in my JS file to imitate the amazing dollar sign DOM selection mechanism in jQuery, using just plain JS. Inside the `query()` function, there's a loop that checks the length of the `elem` (DOM elements) parameter and apply it to get and return the index of each entered DOM element. I was surprised that it only returned the first element.

```
function query(elem) {
    for(var i=0; i<document.querySelectorAll(elem).length; i++) {
        return document.querySelectorAll(elem)[i];
    }
}

query('a').style.color = 'yellow';
```

I believe the problem is with the scope of `return`. I hope someone could point out or correct the wrong with my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are stopping the function after first loop. Delete the `return` keyword.

Comment: Using `return` in this way will exit the from the function and not the loop as you may expect. Instead, you might want to add each element to an array, and then return that array.

Comment: you are returning the 'i' index element which is 0 element take out []

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `return` keyword in the `for` loop, because you will exit the function after first cycle.

I suggest you to make a new Array and push every found element inside it, to be able to manipulate over it.

```js
function query(elem, prop, value) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByTagName(elem);
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    result.push(elems[i]);
    result[i].style[prop] = value;
  }
}

query('h1', 'color', 'red');
```

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>

<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

You can use also use `forEach()` function instead of `for` loop, for a quicker result.

```js
function query(elem) {
  var result = [];
  document.querySelectorAll(elem).forEach(v => result.push(v));
  console.log(result);
}

query('div');
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great tip :)

Comment: but how can I return each element to modify their styles? 'cause I tried to replace the `console.log` with `return result` and nothing changed

Comment: what if I want to change the style of those three?

Comment: but I want the function to be reusable. and I don't want to apply the styles inside the function

Comment: @jst.sixteen You can pass the property and it's value as function arguments. I have edited my answer.

Comment: that's nice. but I want it to be like this: `query('h1').style.color = 'red'`. applying the style to every `h1` in the DOM

Comment: Thanks again, mate

Comment: @jst.sixteen You can upvote&mark answer if you want (:

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the getElementsByTagName DOM to not iterate over all dom elements
Your function is prety much like this native function

document.getElementsByTagName(elem);

The problem with your function is this return a HTMLCollection and you can not apply style to this.

I suggest this for example :

```
function query(elem, callback) {
  var elems =  document.getElementsByTagName(elem);
  for(var i; i < elems.lenght; i++){
      callback(elems[i]);
  }
}

query('a', function(a){
  a.style.color = 'yellow';
})
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName`? What if I want to select class names or IDs like `.element` or `#element`?

Comment: you can create a differents functions or pass this as a param, I suggest this because is less perfomance loop over all DOM elements.

Answer (score -1):

```js
NodeList.prototype.css = function (css) {
 for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
  for (var j in css)
   this[i].style[j] = css[j]
}
document.querySelectorAll('a').css({
 'color' : 'yellow',
 'background-color' : 'black'
})
```

```html
<a href="">The Link</a>
```